# If $X = Y + \operatorname{im}(F)$, prove that $\dim (X) \le 2 \cdot \dim (Y)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am considering this task

> $X$ is linear space, $\dim X < \infty$, $Y \subset X$ is linear
>   subspace and $X = Y + \operatorname{im}(F)$ for some linear
>   transformation $F \in L(Y,X)$. Prove that $\dim X \le 2 \cdot \dim Y$
>   and there is equality iff $F$ is monomorphism and $Y \cap
> > \operatorname{im}(F) = \{0\}$.

### my try

I think that the best option is use this formula: 
$$ \dim (\operatorname{im}(F)) + \dim Y = \dim (Y + \operatorname{im}(F)) + \dim (Y \cap \operatorname{im}(F)) $$
but we know that
 $$ X = Y + \operatorname{im}(F) $$
so 
$$ \dim (\operatorname{im}(F)) + \dim Y = \dim X + \dim (Y \cap \operatorname{im}(F)) $$
Moreover 
$$  \dim (Y \cap \operatorname{im}(F)) \le \dim (\operatorname{im}(F))$$
so 
$$ \dim Y \le \dim X $$
but unfortunately it is trivial because it comes from 
$$ X = Y + \operatorname{im}(F) $$
I am trying on different ways but in each case I finish at something like that.
This task has been added to site a long time ago but I want to use this formula (*only if it's possible*) and I want to show my way of thinking there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: remember that, given a linear transformation $F:Y\rightarrow X$ between finite dimensional linear spaces, then you have the **rank-nullity theorem:**

$$\text{dim}(Y) = \text{dim}(\ker(F)) +\text{dim}(\text{im}(F))$$

which yields two consequences:

1. $\text{dim(im}(F))\leq \text{dim}(Y)$;
2. $\text{dim(im}(F)) = \text{dim}(Y)$ if and only if $\text{dim}(\ker(F))=0$, i.e. if and only if $F$ is a monomorphism.

Item 1 helps you with proving $\text{dim}(X)\leq 2\cdot \text{dim}(Y)$ while item 2 is needed for the second part of your question.